# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una lista de palabras en Tkinter con un Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con mi código. Hago web-scraping con un ciclo `for` y me devuelve una lista de palabras. Lo que busco es mostrar esa misma lista en tkinter. Usé `Label(texto = nm1)` pero solo me muestra la ultima palabra que imprime el `for`. ¿Cómo podría mostrar toda la lista completa?

Dejo mi código.

```
for listt in soup1.find_all('h3',class_="Title"):
    nm1= (listt.getText())

Label(ventana,text=nm1).place(x=22, y=70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> solo me muestra la ultima palabra que imprime el for.

Esto ocurre por que un script de cualquier lenguaje de programación interpretado se ejecutan las instrucciones linea por linea. Obtienes el ultimo elemento de la lista por que se ejecuta primero el ciclo `for` y después se usa la variable en el `Label`.

```
vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

for i in vocales:
    print(i)
    variable = i

print(variable)
```

muestra

```
a
e
i
o
u
u
```

Se muestra cada vocal de la lista `vocales`, por que se hace el `print()` **dentro del ciclo.** Sin embargo, el valor de `variable` fuera del ciclo es `"u"`, debido a que es el ultimo valor que se le asignó dentro del ciclo. Esto deja como conclusión que el valor de variable fuera del ciclo, es el ultimo que tuvo dentro del ciclo.

> Como podria mostrar toda la lista completa?

### Concatenar todos los `getText()`

Puedes definir una variable con un string vació como valor

```
string = ""
```

E irle concatenado cada string retornado por el método `getText()` de cada string navegable en la lista.

```
for nav in navs:
    string += nav.getText() + "\n"
```

*Donde `navs` es la lista de strings navegables que retorna el método `.find_all()` de la sopa*

Aquí se usa `"\n"` (cambio de linea) para separar los textos, se puede usar cualquier cosa. Solo faltaría usar a `string` como texto del `Label`.

```
texto = tk.Label(text = string)
```

### Unir los `getText()` con `str.join()`

Es igualmente válido obtener todos los texto de los string navegables, y unirlos con el método [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

Para obtener los string de `.getText()` de cada elemento en la lista solo basta con una compresión.

```
navs = [text.getText() for text in navs]
string = "\n".join(navs)
```

*Donde navs es la lista que devuelve `find_all()`*

Aquí se está reasignando el valor de `navs` pero esta vez con solo el valor retornado por el método `getText()` de cada string navegable, en vez de cada string navegable. Después se une por `"\n"`, pero puede ser con cualquier otra cosa.

```
texto = tk.Label(text = string)
```

Puedes también hacer uso de funciones como [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) o [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) de functools, para facilitar estas tareas.

Espero te haya ayudado.